# solution of wave equations in odd dimension Evans PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Here I am looking at the proof of theorem 2 below
[image]

Here I have the following difficulties: 
1) In the last two lines, the exponent changes from $\frac{n-1}{2}$ to $\frac{n-3}{2}$, why? Could anyone explain?
2) To show (iii), i.e. check I.C. satisfied. I follow identities in lemma2 (ii) and (iii).(See picture below)
 But it seems I am lost and have messed up my calculation again. Could anyone help?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The set on which the integral is evaluated also changes.  Here he's using polar coordinates to make the calculation work:
$$
\int_{B(x,t)} f(y) dy = \int_0^t \int_{\partial B(x,s)} f(z) d\sigma(z)   ds
$$
where $d\sigma$ is the surface measure on the sphere.  Hence the fundamental theorem of calculus says that
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{B(x,t)} f(y) dy = \int_{\partial B(x,t)} f(z) d\sigma(z). 
$$

In the book he is taking one copy of the operator $t^{-1} \frac{d}{dt}$ and applying it as above, which then decreases the power by one and results in the term
$$
\frac{1}{t} \int_{\partial B(x,t)} \Delta h .
$$

Comment: I will look at this tomorrow, too late here almost 3am...

Answer (score 0):

For one, $$\left(\frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dt}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} = \left(\frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dt}\right)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dt}\right)$$ Then note that the quantity $\left(\frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dt}\right)$ appears to get tucked into the integral. This is why on the second line in question you have a $\frac{1}{t}$ outside the integral. The infinitesimal also changes from $dy$ to $dS$ along with the integral region. Using the formula $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{B(x_0,t)}f dx\right)=\int_{\partial B(x_0,t)} f dS$$ you mentioned as appearing on appendix pg. 628 of Evans, the result follows.

Comment: @math101 I can't use that link. At least not on the computer I'm currently using. Can you make your comment using $\LaTeX$ or with words?

Comment: I tried to comment but can't put that screenshot here, and too hard to latex here, so I put as an answer...is that what you meant?

Comment: yes, have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

According to graydad's answer, I have 
[image]

with use of 
 [image]

Comment: This is roughly what I'm suggesting, although you might want to explain why slipping the $\frac{d}{dt}$ into the integral results in $B(x,t) \to \partial B(x,t)$ and $\Delta h dy \to \Delta h dS$

Comment: I think the last two lines is straight from the formula (see appendix evans p.628) $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{B(x_0,t)}f dx\right)=\int_{\partial B(x_0,t)} f dS$.

Comment: I don't have access to that appendix right now, but that formula does indeed look like exactly what you need to reach your equality! I have updated my answer so that it resembles one that provides an answer to your question.

Comment: Do you have any other questions about this problem?